# Kendo UI Grid trying to select row with the following configuration

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In my AngularJS application im using Kendo UI Grid.
I have the following Kendo UI Grid options and dataSource. What im trying to do is to somehow add click event on each row. I have definitions for each column but I cant access the whole row which contains the columns. Is this possible without the use of rowTemplate and altRowTemplate. Because if i use them i have to redefine the whole table again.

HTML:

```
<div
            k-options="ctrl.mainGridOptions"
            k-rebind="ctrl.mainGridOptions"
            kendo-grid="ctrl.gridInstance">
    </div>
```

Grid Options:

```
  this.mainGridOptions = {
                dataSource: {
                    data: this.allRows,
                    pageSize: 150,
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            fields: {
                                activityType: { type: "string" },
                                communicationType: { type: "string" },
                                count: { type: "number" },
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    aggregate: [
                        {
                            field: "activityType",
                            aggregate: "count"
                        },
                        {
                            field: "communicationType",
                            aggregate: "count"
                        },
                        {
                            field: "count",
                            aggregate: "count"
                        }
                    ],
                    group: {
                        field: this.groupBy.field,
                        aggregates: [
                            {
                                field: "activityType",
                                aggregate: "count"
                            },
                            {
                                field: "communicationType",
                                aggregate: "count"
                            },
                            {
                                field: "count",
                                aggregate: "count"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                scrollable: {
                    virtual: true
                },
                sortable: true,
                resizable: false,
                pageable: false,
                groupable: true,
                columnMenu: true,
                filterable: true,
                reorderable: false,
                columns: [
                    {
                        headerTemplate: '<md-checkbox ng-model="dataItem.checked" ng-change="ctrl.headerSelected(dataItem)" aria-label="row check" ng-transclude=""></md-checkbox>',
                        template: '<md-checkbox stop-event  ng-class="{\'row-selected\' : ctrl.checkVisible.length > 0 || ctrl.headerCb}" ng-model="dataItem.checked" ng-change="ctrl.rowSelected(dataItem, dataItem.cbIndex)" aria-label="item check"></md-checkbox>',
                        width:"50px"
                    },
                    {
                        field: "activityType",
                        title: "activityType",
                        aggregates: ['count'],
                        template: '<span ng-bind="dataItem.activityType"></span>',
                        groupHeaderTemplate: '<span class="aggregate-wrapper" ng-click="ctrl.toggleGroupCollapse($event)"><span>' + "activityType" + ':' + '</span>' + ' #= value # (Count: #= count#)</span>'
                    },{
                        field: "communicationType",
                        title: "communicationType",
                        aggregates: ['count'],
                        groupHeaderTemplate: '<span class="aggregate-wrapper" ng-click="ctrl.toggleGroupCollapse($event)"><span>' + "communicationType" + '</span>' + ' #= value # (Count: #= count#)</span>'
                    },{
                        field: "count",
                        title: "count",
                        aggregates: ['count'],
                        template: '<div layout="row" layout-align="center center">' +
                        '<md-progress-linear flex="80"  md-mode="determinate" ng-value="ctrl.calcProgressValue(dataItem.count)"></md-progress-linear>' +
                        '<span flex  style="text-align:right" ng-bind="dataItem.count"> </span>' +
                        '</div>',
                        groupHeaderTemplate: '<span class="aggregate-wrapper" ng-click="ctrl.toggleGroupCollapse($event)"><span>' + "count" + ':' + '</span>' + ' #= value # (Count: #= count#)</span>'
                    },
                    {
                        field: "",
                        title: null,
                        template: '<span class="action-controls"><i class="material-icons">label</i><i class="material-icons">star_rate</i><i class="material-icons"> more_vert </i></span>',
                        width: '200px'
                    }
                ],
            };
```

This is the data i pass into the kendo grid

```
this.allRows = [
{
        "activityType": 2,
        "activitySubType": 10,
        "count": 265
      },
      {
        "activityType": 2,
        "activitySubType": 1,
        "count": 238
      },
      {
        "activityType": 7,
        "activitySubType": 3,
        "count": 102
      },
      {
        "activityType": 6,
        "activitySubType": 12,
        "count": 142
      },
      {
        "activityType": 6,
        "activitySubType": 18,
        "count": 98
      },
      {
        "activityType": 2,
        "activitySubType": 19,
        "count": 145
      }
];
```

Comment: Let me make myself clear.. All you want is to have a click event on all the rows and on click you need the entire row data.. Right?

Comment: exactly and make on click change scope variable and then with ng-class on the row change its classes

Comment: I am not aware of Angular stuff.. will giving you control on click and getting you the row data .. will that help you? you must carry on from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`change` event](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-change), which is triggered when use changes a *row or a cell* in the grid when the [`selectable`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-selectable) option is set to `true`:

```
change: function() {
    // Get your row's data
    var dataItem = this.dataItem(this.select());
}
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/ecaVE)

Comment: it works but why i cant select a second row, when i do the first row gets unselected

Comment: I just want to call a  function when a row is clicked thatas all. Using selectable: "multiple, row" it need to hit ctrl in order to select second row.

Comment: @GeorgiAntonov to call a *function* when the row is clicked you just have to call it inside the event. To select more than one row without ctrl key you'll have to use a custom code i think.

Comment: ok given this configuration is it easy to add attribute to all table rows ?

Comment: @GeorgiAntonov any property you add on the objects of the `allRows` array will be available in your `dataItem`. Don't need to be on any grid column at all. Example: Your grid haves 3 columns but your dataItems haves 5 properties, all those 5 properties are available in the dataItem.